# How to filter a transposed pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a transposed df like so

```
    id       0          1           2            3
0  1361     Spain     Russia     South Africa   China
1  1741     Portugal  Cuba       UK             Ukraine
2  1783     Germany   USA        France         Egypt
3  1353     Brazil    Russia     Japan          Kenya
4  1458     India     Romania    Holland        Nigeria
```

How could I get all rows where there is 'er' so it'll return me this

```
   id       0           1           2            3
2  1783     Germany   USA        France         Egypt
4  1458     India     Romania    Holland        Nigeria
```

because 'er' is contained in Germany and Nigeria.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `contains`

```
df[df.apply(lambda x :x.str.contains(pat='er')).any(1)]
Out[96]: 
             id        0        1        2     3
2 1783  Germany      USA   France    Egypt  None
4 1458    India  Romania  Holland  Nigeria  None
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) across rows:

```
df = df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('er').any(), axis=1)]

print(df)
     id        0        1        2        3
2  1783  Germany      USA   France    Egypt
4  1458    India  Romania  Holland  Nigeria
```

Comment: @Del-m10 Glad to help.